# update Cookie's value from 3rd party application

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, httpcookie, js-cookie

I have 2 websites `site.com` and `pixel.com`. A pixel script is embeded in `site.com` for event tracking, when user visit `site.com`, `pixel.com` sets a cookie with `uuid` in `site.com`. and when user login to `site.com` , `pixel.com` get user's real ID and update the pre-existing cookie.

Frist cookie was set using `JS` from `pixel.com`. and now again i need to update same cookie with new value from `pixel.com` but using PHP.

Is there any way to achive this?

Comment: If you want to set a cookie under `site.com`, sure, you can do that with PHP.

Comment: from `pixel.com` , how i can approach that?

Comment: You can not set a cookie for a different domain from the server side. If your `pixel.com` needs to set a cookie under `site.com`, then the only way to do that is via JavaScript, that _runs_ under `site.com`. That JavaScript itself could be _loaded from_ `pixel.com` though in this situation.